# How to retrieve details from a repeater control to display in modal popup

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a repeater control which displays an image and some basic information like DateTime and Prouct Id. On clicking an Image I need to run another query and show details in a seperate popup.I know how to do the popup.
I want to know how I can fetch the DateTime and ProductId from the repeater  and use them in the button  click event of the image?

I have my code for the repeater below :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMonitorSummary" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMonitorSummary_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Pnl" runat="server">
            <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                <h5 class="ui-widget-header">
                    <%# Eval("Name").ToString().Length > 9 ? (Eval("Name") as string).Substring(0, 9) : Eval("Name")%>
                </h5>
                <div id="divHover">
                    <asp:ImageButton Width="80px" ID="btnPerformanceImage" onclick="btnPerformanceImage_Click" runat="server" Height="45px">
                    </asp:ImageButton>
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip" style="display: none">
                    <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
                        <%# Eval("DateTime") %><br />
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal">
                        ErrorRatingCalls =
                        <%# Eval("ProductId")%><br />
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal">
                        TotalRatingCalls =
                        <%# Eval("TotalCalls")%>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: normal">
                        SuccessRate =
                        <%# Eval("PassPercentage") + "%" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I also have the button click event below :

```
protected void btnPerformanceImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
            (this, this.GetType(), "callScriptFunction", "ViewModelPopup1();", true);
}
```

All I want to know is how I can fetch the values that are already bound to the repeater control, When I click on an image which inside the repeater control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling click on the button itself, you should rather make use of `ItemCommand` event of the `Repeater` control. As a `CommandArgument` you can pass `ProductId`, and then inside the handler use it to retrieve rest of the info from the DB. Or you can even include all needed values into `CommandArgument` as a single string and do some parsing afterwards:

```
<asp:Repeater ... OnItemCommand="rptMonitorSummary_ItemCommand" ... >
   ...
   <asp:ImageButton ... CommandName="ShowPopup" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId") + "," + Eval("DateTime") %>'>
   </asp:ImageButton>
   ...
</asp:Repeater>
```

The handler might look like this:

```
protected void rptMonitorSummary_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string[] tokens = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');
    int productId = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
    DateTime dateTime = Date.Time.Parse(tokens[1]);
    // the rest of the handling here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [OnItemCommand](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-Repeater-OnItemCommand-Event-using-C-sharp.aspx) event to fetch values out of the repeater control.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMonitorSummary" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMonitorSummary_OnItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptMonitorSummary_ItemCommand">
```

.
.
.

```
<asp:ImageButton Width="80px" ID="btnPerformanceImage" CommandName="Popup" runat="server" Height="45px"></asp:ImageButton>
```

.
.
.

```
protected void rptMonitorSummary_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.CommandName == "Popup")  
    {
        DataRowView row = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row;

        string data1 = Convert.ToString(row["Data1"]);
        string data2 = Convert.ToString(row["Data2"]);

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
                (this, this.GetType(), string.Format("callScriptFunction", "ViewModelPopup1('{0}','{1}');", data1, data2), true);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the OnClick inside your Button, use the OnItemCommand="rptMonitorSummary_ItemCommand" in your Repeater

Then on the code behind

```
    protected void rptMonitorSummary_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
          //  e.CommandName and e.CommandArgument will let you know what was clicked
    }
```

Your button can look something like this

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPerformanceImage" Text="Whatever" CommandName="OpenImage" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductId") %>' />
```

So then you know what the user clicked on and can change the popup to suit it

Answer (score 0):

you can set a class attribute name for both div tags wich contains the date value and ProductId value and next get them with jquery .find('classname') to retreive their values.